# How do I auto activate and destroy in a plant uml sequence diagram

Tags: plantuml

In PlantUML adding activation lines in a sequence diagram can be very messy. Is there any way to make it auto activate and deactivate without all the extra text?

e.g.

Generate Sequence diagram without activation lines

```
@startuml

First -> Second
Second -> Third
Third -> Second
Second ->  First

@enduml
```

[image]

But to add the activation lines its gets quite messy

```
@startuml

First -> Second : message
activate First
activate Second
Second -> Third: message
activate Third
Third -> Second: response
deactivate Third
Second ->  First: response
deactivate First
deactivate Second

@enduml
```

[image]

I'm wondering if there is its possible to have it auto detect the likely create destroy points automatically

Comment: I doubt that's possible in any built-in way. There's no way for it to know when the active period should end.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes (2017)** with **autoactivate on**; the syntax is still in [incubation](http://plantuml.com/incubation), however it has been part of the distribution for some time.

Note that in all cases you still need to manually activate the First one, because there's no incoming message.

#### Compact syntax

If you want to maintain control of the (de)activation, you can express activation/deactivation with `++` and `--` symbols on the same line to activate the target.

```
activate First
First -> Second ++ : message12
Second -> Third ++ : message23
Third -> Second -- : response32
Second ->  First -- : response21
deactivate First
```

[image]

#### autoactivate on

With your original description you will quickly find out that you need to describe your lines properly as a return, otherwise you'll be activating ad nauseam.

```
autoactivate on
activate First
First -> Second
Second -> Third
Third --> Second
Second --> First
deactivate First
```

[image]